# In mobile showing background good, but in bluestacks showing white background

Tags: java, android, background, bluestacks

I have problem, i setted bakground image, it showing good in mobile, but in bluestacks emulator it shows white background.... Why? What is the problem?
Can somebody help me to fix this problem?

The problem with: android:background="@drawable/map_new_9"

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/base">

...
...


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/base1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/base2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1920dp"
            android:background="@drawable/map_new_9"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Probably a BlueStacks issue. Try the android emulator in Android Studio.

Comment: My computer is sh*t and i can't run Android Studio's emulator, so i test on my phone... :( But thanks for the answer